# Questions on dark matter observations in galaxy clusters

Tags: general-relativity, dark-matter, galaxy-cluster, gravitational-lensing

For cluster of galaxies we can observe velocity distributions and so we can deduce mass from multiwavelength observations. I suppose total mass of the cluster could be deduced by observing velocities of galaxies and applying virial theorem. Is it be done using general relativity or just with classical mechanics ?

An other way could be whith looking at gravitational lensing it causes on far galaxies.

Are these two methods giving same results ?

Comment: Classical mechanics is all that is needed. And yes. I'll let someone else provide the details.